# get epoch time in js using new date for 7 days back midnight in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I am trying to get 7 days back epoch 12 am time but I am getting 7 days back time but same as the time at present like at 5 pm it gives 7 days back but at 5pm istead of 12 am.
below code is what I tried:

```
  let createdAt = new Date();
 createdAt = new Date().setDate(createdAt.getDate()-7);
```

please help me to understand , how to get 12 am of 7 days back?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero the time too, e.g.

```
let createdAt = new Date();
createdAt.setHours(0,0,0,0);
createdAt = new Date().setDate(createdAt.getDate()-7);
```

The last line could also be:

```
createdAt = createdAt.setDate(createdAt.getDate() - 7);
```

since the *set* methods return the time value of the updated date.

Or create a new Date from just the date parts and get its time value, e.g.

```js
let d = new Date();
let ms = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate() - 7).getTime();

console.log(ms + '\n' + new Date(ms).toString());
```